# Remotely connect to a database instance on a Azure VM without RDP?

Tags: networking, sql-server, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

## Preface

I'm a developer by trade, so network security isn't really my purview. However, solving problems is my purview, and I've got one with which I need help.

Also, please forgive me if I get any technical terms incorrect. I can talk development well, I no talk network security good.

## Current Solution

My company uses a Azure VM running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. The server runs instances of both SQL Server and Oracle (not sure the version numbers).

Currently, if I want to connect to either of those database instances, I need to RDP into the Windows server, open `SSMS` or `SQL Developer`, and connect to localhost.

## Desired Solution

I'd like to be able to connect to the database servers via the database clients installed on my local machine.

I don't want to have to RDP since that means we have to share the one RDP slot.

## Considerations

I think the reason we use the RDP solution is that whoever set up the server did not know how to configure the firewall to allow us to do what we need to do.

The server isn't completely closed off from the Internet. Obviously, the RDP ports are open, and also we can publish web applications to it via Visual Studio. And it does have Internet facing web sites on it. Those seem like plenty of great attack vectors.

## Question

- How bad is it to have SQL Server and Oracle ports open to the Internet?

  - Are they more vulnerable attack vectors than RDP and HTTP?
- How should we configure the server to allow developers to connect to the databases via their local machines?
- Is a VPN a good solution ? I'd hate to go that route since every VPN client I've ever worked with is a pain. And I'd hate to inflict unnecessary pain on my fellow developers.
- Can we configure the server's firewall to whitelist inbound connections on the DB porting from the office IP ?

  - That would exclude people working from home to connect to the server, but they could always VPN into the office network (necessary evil at that point).

Answer (score 1):

`How bad is it to have SQL Server and Oracle ports open to the Internet?` - Well, that's largely opinion based but suffice it to say that you'll have two additional attack vectors to worry about. How knowledgeable are you at securing SQL Server and Oracle?

`How should we configure the server to allow developers to connect to the databases via their local machines?` - If you must do this then you'll want to configure your Azure NSG (Network Security Group) to allow connections to SQL Server and Oracle **ONLY** from your specific ip address or ip addresses, meaning only from the public ip address from which your office traffic originates. This will effectively restrict access to SQL Server and Oracle to only those connections originating from your office.

Comment: `How knowledgeable are you at securing SQL Server and Oracle?` not at all.

Answer (score 1):

> How should we configure the server to allow developers to connect to
>   the databases via their local machines?

Are the Vms on a VNET? i'm guessing they are, if that is the case but you don't want to use site-to-site VPN have you considered configuring Point-to-Site VPN connections form your developers PCs? Point-to-Site connections are easy to set up. Microsoft even let you download a configured VPN client so you don't have the hassle of setting that side of things up. it also has the added advantage that you don't need to open the SQL ports to the internet.

you can find details here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal

or watch an excellent video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8m2MAhO_I8

> Can we configure the server's firewall to whitelist inbound
>   connections on the DB porting from the office IP ?

Yes, if these are ASM VMs you can configure endpoint ACLs to restrict access to certain IP Addresses and Ranges, and for both ASM and ARM VMs you can configure Network Security Groups (NSGs) that can also restrict access based on IP addresses and ports.

Hope this helps.